# How can electronic transitions in atoms contribute to the vibration of molecules?

Tags: visible-light, electrons, vibrations, raman-spectroscopy

In Raman spectroscopy, light is inelastically scattered from a sample and the shift in the scattered frequency (the Raman shift) is related to the vibrational modes of the sample.

> [...] and should not be confused with emission (fluorescence or
>   phosphorescence) where a molecule in an excited electronic state emits
>   a photon of energy and returns to the ground electronic state, in many
>   cases to a vibrationally excited state on the ground electronic state
>   potential energy surface. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_spectroscopy))

But why inelastic scattering induces vibrational transitions? In other words, how can *electronic transitions in atoms* contribute to the *vibration of molecules*?

[image]([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_spectroscopy))

Comment: What is holding the molecules together? If you disturb the electrons, why would the molecules not vibrate?

Comment: @JonCuster this is part of what I don't understand: to my understanding, "disturbed electron" = excited electronic state, while the vibration is explained with a virtual state. I guess I'm also asking why virtual states induce a change in dipole moment.

Comment: Perhaps the difficulty is in figuring out what the 'virtual' state really means here. If you take a 'simple' diatomic molecule, you could figure out the ground state electronic and atomic configuration look like. One could even look at the variation in the inter-atomic potential for 'small' changes in the inter-atomic spacing. This gives you the vibrational states. Now excite an electron into an empty molecular orbital. The interatomic spacing will also have to need to change to be in 'equilibrium'. It is a mixed problem now, between the electronic and atomic configuration.

Comment: <Continued> - But, the atomic positions change much slower than the electron positions. In Raman scattering, will you actually get to an equilibrium 'excited state'? Well, no, you won't. So you call it a 'virtual' state, but I guess don't tell the students just what you mean.  Sigh.

Comment: @JonCuster excitation into an empty orbital = electronic transition to an excited state (i.e. like in fluorescence), which I thought is not the case with vibrations.

Comment: @JonCuster and even if it's not in equilibrium with interatomic distance, why call it virtual if it's an actual orbital?